# Can I hang up using a button?

Tags: htc-sense, calls, htc-desire-z, buttons

When I'm on a phone call nothing is more important than the ability to *hang up*. If, for whatever reason, I suddenly find myself in an embarrassing situation or interrupted by something important, I *must* be able to terminate the call.

Currently the only option, that I know of, is a medium sized red button on the touch screen. I think this is deficient for a few reasons:

- the touch screen doesn't always behave as you want (too sensitive, or not sensitive enough) - how often do you listen to chat radio shows and the callers are always "accidently" hitting the dial buttons in the middle of conversation
- the GUI may be running slowly and be unresponsive

It there a way of mapping a generic button (such as a camera button on the HTC Desire) to perform the hang-up action? Perhaps someone could write such a service!

Comment: Not to mention if you happen to navigate away from the call screen it'll take a couple clicks to get back to where you can hang up.

Comment: I don't use bluetooth, but can't you use a bluetooth headset to terminate a call?

Answer (score 19):

`Settings | Accessibility | Power button ends call`

> During a call, pressing Power ends call instead of turning off screen.

Comment: No such setting on my HTC Desire Z with Froyo 2.2

Comment: Too bad. It's one of my favorite hidden features of my Droid.

Comment: There is such a setting on the Galaxy Tab.. just not on the HTC..

Comment: Actually this setting on the Galaxy Tab is a curse! I tried calling a call centre, and whenever the screen turned off I pressed the power button to turn the screen back on, which aborted the call! I couldn't get through to the call centre to press different numbers on the keypad once the screen powered off! Terrible.. So I had to switch this option OFF on my Galaxy Tab. Who was the "bright spark" that thought a hang up button was unnecessary???

Comment: Excellent! This option is present in the LG Optimus One model. Finally! Thanks.

Comment: Feature not present in CM6 - Magic

Comment: Not present in HTC Wildfire.

Comment: @Mob: Unfortunately, that is just one downside of carriers and OEMs "messing" with Android.

Answer (score 5):

My first thought was the same as [Al Everett's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/can-i-hang-up-using-a-button/2977#2977) but if you, for some reason, don't have that setting, you can achieve it through Tasker.

1. New Profile -> Event -> Hardware -> choose the button event you'd like -> Done
2. `+` button on the left bottom corner to add a task
3. Phone -> End Call -> Done

And you are ready to go ;)

Comment: you mean you can or can't?

Comment: Yes, it is possible through tasker. I'll update my answer

Comment: It seems to me the camera button would be an excellent candidate.