# Settings - Accessibility warning: "Downloaded accessibility application is required to activate" -- What should I do?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, samsung-galaxy-s, settings

If I choose the '**Settings - Accessibility**' option on my Samsung Galaxy S, the following text is displayed: '*Downloaded accessibility application is required to activate*'.

I searched the Droid Market for 'accessibility' but am not sure that this is the correct way to install this (system?) application.

Anyone any idea what and where from I should install ? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Its probably talking about either Talkback, Soundback, or Kickback.
(Talkback being when you divert to home it with articulate "home"; Soundback producing a ping; Kickback producing a vibration)
But i would make sure to double think which one you prefer or really need being that you will not be able to uninstall once downloaded.
Once downloaded it should give you an option.***

Answer (score 1):

You probably need [TalkBack](http://www.appbrain.com/app/talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback).

Comment: @Al Everett: Do be honest , I don't know what this option does. I only saw your answer here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/hang-up-using-button and decided to enable the option you talked about, only to discover that this option gave the above message.

Answer (score 0):

When I go into Accessibility on my Froyo Galaxy S I get this:

> **No accessibility applications found**
>
> You do not have any accessibility
>   applications. You can download a
>   screen reader from Android Market.
>
> Click OK to install screen reader

Clicking OK takes me to the Market search page for the [Talkback](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-google-android-marvin-talkback-zwxB.aspx) app. Specifically the Market has been searched for [`pname:com.google.android.marvin.talkback`](http://pname%3acom.google.android.marvin.talkback)