# Disconnecting a call

Tags: calls

Can anybody tell me how to disconnect the call in between. The screen on my Samsung Galaxy 3 becomes disabled during the call , it becomes very difficult to get the screen back during the call to disconnect.

Comment: Generally you simply use the power button to re-enable the screen (if the proximity sensor doesn't automatically do it) and hit "end call". However, some people like to be able to do it with their hardware buttons, which is addressed in this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/hang-up-using-button

Comment: @Al I think that's good enough for an answer

Comment: Definitely a solid answer.

Comment: Okay, [done](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4435/disconnecting-a-call/4454#4454).

Answer (score 3):

Generally you simply use the power button to re-enable the screen (if the proximity sensor doesn't automatically do it) and hit "end call".

However, some people like to be able to do it with their hardware buttons, which is addressed in this question: [Can I hang up using a button?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/hang-up-using-button)