# How to return to call when screen blanked

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, calls, hardware

I was on a call and I was put on hold by the other person. The screen blanked after a time (as expected). 
When I hit the power button to return to the call. I found the call dropped.

How can I resume the phone without losing the call.
(2.3-gingerbread samsung-nexus-s)

Comment: Related, in that someone was looking for the opposite behavior: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/hang-up-using-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in settings > accessibility and see if theres an option for the power button to end the call. If there is make sure it's unchecked.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Wouldnt have thought to look under accessibility.....